# Graphviz -- splines = "curved" doesn't work

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to compile a finite state machine (FSM) visual representation in `.pdf` by using a `.dot` source file:

```
// Use directional graph "digraph" opossed to "graph"
digraph {

    rankdir = TB;
    nodesep = 0.5;
    ranksep = 0.25;
    //splines = "curved";
    //splines = "ortho";
    
    // A:
    node[
        fontname = "IBM Plex Mono Text Italic",
        fontsize = 8,
        shape = circle,
        style = "filled",
        fillcolor = "#DDDDDD",
        fontcolor = "#333333",
        color = "#AAAAAA",
        penwidth = 0.1;
    ]

    // B:
    edge[
        fontname = "IBM Plex Mono Bold",
        //style = "dotted",
        fontsize = 8,
        arrowhead = normal,
        arrowsize = 0.4,
        penwidth = 0.1;
        fontcolor = "#444444",
        color = "#777777",
    ]

    // C:
    graph[
        fontname = "IBM Plex Mono Bold",
        fontsize=8,
        rank = TB,
        style = "filled",
        fontcolor = "#444444",
        color = "#EEEEEE",
    ]
    
    // C:
    000[label = "start", shape = "plain", fillcolor = "none"];
    001[label = "q1", shape = "doublecircle"];
    002[label = "q2"];
    003[label = "q3"];

    // D:
    000->001;
    001->001[label="2"];
    001->002[label="1"];
    002->001[label="0"];
    002->002[label="2"];
    002->003[label="1"];
    003->002[label="0"];
    003->003[label="2"];
    001->003[label="1"];
    003->001[label="0"];

}
```

And this compiles almost perfectly *(except for the straight inner transitions)*:

[image]

If I uncomment the line `splines = "ortho";` at the top it compiles like this *(it is ugly, but I want to show, that it works)*:

[image]

But when I instead uncomment the line `splines = "curved";` *(this one is the one that I need)* at the top, disaster happens:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: What version of graphviz are you using? Run from the command line, my dot.exe which is latest 2.47.1 says "Warning: edge labels with splines=curved not supported in dot - use xlabels" when I uncomment the line `splines = "curved";` and then generates something inadequate - but the message accounts for that.

Comment: I am on Debian system and my graphviz is `2.40.1`. You are right. Compilation with `dot -Tpdf main.dot > main.pdf` yields this warning: `Warning: edge labels with splines=curved not supported in dot - use xlabels`. Do you maybe know how to use `xlabels`?

Comment: Nope. I believe it allows you to manually place the labels. FWIW I'd go with the default output - if you desperately need the straightlines to be curved add some invisible nodes in the edge so they curve.

Comment: I will wait for Debian 11 that has graphviz version 2.42.2 and hope that curved splines are supported there. I wish I knew how to verify this. I tried searching commits on graphviz's official GitLab but I was only able to find that there were patches regarding curved splines 6 years ago: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/commits/main?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=curved

Comment: As 2.47.1 has the same message, you are very optimistic.