# Drawing an open addressing shape with ports

Tags: hashtable, graphviz, dot

### Attempt

[Drawing graphs with dot](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) p. 16 they draw a separate chaining hash table. "Records sometimes look better if their input height is set to a small value."

```
nodesep=0.05;
node [width=.1, height=.1];
```

I would like to draw an open addressing scheme type graph that has one node and different ports to represent items in the hash table; the ports have interconnections based on their closed address.

```
digraph {
    node [shape=plain, style=filled, fillcolor="Gray95"];
    edge [arrowsize=0.5];
    set [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="Gray90" PORT="0">0x0</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>0x1</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="Gray90" PORT="2">0x2</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD PORT="3">0x3</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="Gray90" PORT="4">0x4</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD PORT="5">0x5</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="Gray90" PORT="6">0x6</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD ALIGN="RIGHT" PORT="7">0x7</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>>];
    set:2:e -> set:3:e;
    set:3:e -> set:4:e;
    set:6:e -> set:7:e;
    set:0:e -> set:5:e;
}
```

Which results in the following graph. It's loops are much to big, and overlapping with other loops that makes it very difficult to read.

[image: Output of the previous graph.]

### Tried

It appears that the spline strongly wants to leave the node and spend a certain amount of time out before re-entering. So I thought these might work. However, the ones that looked promising don't appear to work with edges that loop back to the same shape. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488071/graphviz-splines-curved-doesnt-work).

```
splines=none; // doesn't draw edges
splines=ortho; // draws concentric circles around node?
splines=curved; // draws one nice and gives up
splines=true; // default; draws a huge mess
splines=polyline; // angled, auto-edges no different
splines=false; // straight, auto-edges no different
```

I tried overlap, maybe the edges to be drawn more relaxed?

```
overlap=true; // no effect
graph [overlap=true]; // no effect
mclimit=6; // no effect
```

Maybe if I make the size bigger or the arrows smaller it will give more space?

```
node [fontsize=48]; // big, but no effect on the edges
edge [arrowsize=0.5]; // small, but otherwise no effect
edge [weight=3, minlen=3]; // again, there is only one shape
```

I tried compass ":c" (for centre?) and ":_" (appears to be similar to north) and ":e" and ":w" in alternation, but no luck. Is there something that could make these loops smaller in size?

Comment: Are you open to non-Graphviz solutions?

Comment: @sroush I use this in debugging; I like that GraphViz on has a viewer that automatically adjusts to the latest file when it gets overwritten, but I'm open to suggestions if they are easy to write. I'm also not set on one-node only, but it's a lot of empty space, otherwise.

Comment: I successfully tried to reduce the space using free-floating shapes, but I have different columns; they are much more difficult to line up, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up on a single node & packed in multiple nodes.

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR
    nodesep=".02"
    splines=true //line //false //curved

    node [shape=rect, style=filled, fillcolor="Gray95", height=0 width=0 margin=".01,.01"];
    edge [arrowsize=0.5 constraint=false];

    N0 [label="0x0"]
    N1 [label="0x1"]
    N2 [label="0x2"]
    N3 [label="0x3"]
    N4 [label="0x4"]
    N5 [label="0x5"]
    N6 [label="0x6"]
    N7 [label="0x7"]

    N2:e -> N3:e  
    N3:e -> N4:e  
    N6:e -> N7:e  
    N0:e -> N5:e  

    // following edges keep nodes in order
    edge [weight=200 style=invis]
    N0 -> N1 
    N1 -> N2
    N2 -> N3
    N3 -> N4
    N5 -> N6
    N6 -> N7
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't constraint be true on the invis edges?

Comment: Nope, rankdir is LR, so we don't want the nodes ranked, we want them all in the same rank.